# can I get coordinates of objects in a image with yolov5?

Tags: object-detection, yolo, yolov5

I want to know, if it is possible to use yolov5 to find objects in an image and than give back the type of object and where it is in the picture? Not only the image with the bounding boxes

Answer (score 0):

found it:
results.pandas().xyxy[0]
or
results.xyxy[0]